# Open the same Activity with new parameteres

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service

I searched a lot before asking my question and tried many ways but none of them worked with me.
I'm making a radio player ! so i have a listview containing a list of radio station every items contains some information with the link to be played when i click on the item.

So, when a click on item i create a new activity containing a player( the player will start a new service who will play the stream)
when i click back to the listview the activity of the player is removed from the stack.
when i click on the notification the application crashes because the activity is not found.
I've tried to override the BackButton ,but when i click back the apps return to the home screen :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

i tried adding some flags to the intent before starting ! but it won't work either !!
So , i'm completly blocked  ,can't find any method to handle this problem
Thanks for your help !
If you want some source code please tell me i will update my post!
thanks
Update : the log :

```
07-27 00:02:20.650: E/dalvikvm(9406): The following issues were seen:
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MSoft.socialradio/com.MSoft.socialradio.StationListenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at com.MSoft.socialradio.StationListenActivity.onCreate(StationListenActivity.java:91)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
07-27 00:02:22.390: E/AndroidRuntime(9406):     ... 11 more
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.MSoft.socialradio.MyMediaPlayerService@210972d0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2757)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:150)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at com.MSoft.socialradio.MyMediaPlayerService.onStartCommand(MyMediaPlayerService.java:51)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2740)
07-27 00:02:31.900: E/AndroidRuntime(10122):    ... 10 more
```

The service Player:

```
package com.MSoft.socialradio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyMediaPlayerService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    Timer timer ;
    TextView songName;
    String GetSongInfo;
    MetadataTask metaTask=null;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private boolean      isPlaying = false;
    String url;
    private static int classID = 579; // just a number

    public static String START_PLAY = "START_PLAY";
    final static String MY_ACTION = "IcyData";
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(START_PLAY, false)) {
            url=intent.getStringExtra("url");
            play();  




        }
        return Service.START_STICKY;    
    }



    private void play() {
        if (!isPlaying) {           
            isPlaying = true;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, StationListenActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("Social Radio")
                .setContentText("Now Playing:under Construction")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .build();

            /*mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rehab); // change this for your file
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // this will make it loop forever
            mediaPlayer.start();*/
            //url = "http://ice.abradio.cz:80/hit90128.mp3"; // your URL here
            Log.i("play","playing:"+url);
            try {
                 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

                    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }



            startForeground(classID, notification);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("on Destory","Stopping");
        stop();
        //timer.cancel();
    }   

    private void stop() {
        if (isPlaying) {
            Log.i("on Destory","Stopping");
            isPlaying = false;
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            }
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        StartTimer();
    }
    public InputStream OpenHttpPOSTConnection(String url) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // ---the key/value pairs to post to the server---

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            Log.d("OpenHttpPOSTConnection TIMEOUT", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("OpenHttpPOSTConnection", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return inputStream;
    }
    public void StartTimer() 
    {
        try {
            final URL Url = new URL(url);
            Log.i("StartTimer",url);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while(mediaPlayer!=null)
                    {
                    try {
                        Log.i("StartTimer","Sending:");

                        metaTask=new MetadataTask();
                        metaTask.execute(Url);
                        Intent intent_braodcast = new Intent();
                        intent_braodcast.setAction(MY_ACTION);

                           intent_braodcast.putExtra("DATAPASSED", GetSongInfo);

                           sendBroadcast(intent_braodcast); 
                           Log.i("StartTimer","Sending:");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }
                }
            }).start();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("StartTimer Exception","");
        }

    }
    protected class MetadataTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, IcyStreamMeta> {
        protected  IcyStreamMeta streamMeta;

        @Override
        protected IcyStreamMeta doInBackground(URL... urls) {

            try {
                if (OpenHttpPOSTConnection(urls[0].toString()) == null) {
                    //songName.setText("Error in connection");

                    throw new Exception("Error network");
                }
                streamMeta = new IcyStreamMeta(urls[0]);
                if (streamMeta == null) {
                    //songName.setText("Error in connection");
                    throw new Exception("Error in connection");
                }
                streamMeta.refreshMeta();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: Handle
                Log.e(MetadataTask.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i("ExceptionDoinBackground", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return streamMeta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(IcyStreamMeta result) {
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                if (streamMeta.GetFullData() == "")
                    GetSongInfo="No Icy Data";
                else {
                    GetSongInfo=streamMeta.GetFullData();
                    //songName.setText(streamMeta.GetFullData());
                    Log.i("Onposteexecute", streamMeta.GetFullData());
                }

                // txtArtist.setText(streamMeta.getArtist());
                // txtTitle.setText(streamMeta.getTitle());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO: Handle
                Log.e(MetadataTask.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean when you say "when I click on the notification"

Comment: I've created a service that play the stream and add a notification in android when :Intent intent = new Intent(this, StationListenActivity.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
   
   Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
           .setContentTitle("Social Radio")
           .setContentText("Now Playing:under Construction")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
           .setContentIntent(pi)
           .build();

Comment: Please, add your error logs

Comment: And what do you have in the line MyMediaPlayerService.java:51 ?

Comment: The service that handle the player it takes the url from the activty and play it.i will poste it too

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the service the first time adding the url, so in the line MyMediaPlayerService.java:51 works fine. When you start the service from the nofitication, you are not setting a url in the arguments. The service intent:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, StationListenActivity.class);

should have the url

Comment: Yes it's true for the url i added it ! but the problem is the Activity that handle the service is destroyed when the back button is pressed so the apps crashes when i click in the notification :(

Comment: what do you have in the line 91 in StationListenActivity?

Comment: This worked for me Intent intent = new Intent(this, StationListenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("url", url);PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
   
   Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
           .setContentTitle("Social Radio")
           .setContentText("Now Playing:under Construction")
           .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
           .setContentIntent(pi)
           .build();---

Comment: but i have to save the variables in the activity because when it's opened like it was the the first time